# how to safely use config files and environments in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, environment

my question starts from this article [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments). I followed it along, but this passage:

> Security Considerations
>
> Since these files will potentially contain secure information, such as
> API_KEY, I’d recommend not checking them into version control and
> instead using a secure file storage system like 1Password to contain
> copies of Development.xcconfig, Staging.xcconfig and
> Production.xcconfig.

makes me wonder what writer is talking about. Configs file are needed be in the app to work, I don't think I could put them aside. if someone could help I need to understand

- how to handle those files in safety
- how should use this config files, should I put them different (id present) endpoint based on environment? could I put there different things such images names, default values for variables etch?

Answer (score 0):

I also wonder how this could be handled, putting them in some 1Password storage.

If you feel unsafe by checking in those files (why would you? Anyone who accesses the source code needs to somehow access some API using some key), you could

- Handle this by .gitignore
- Create a softlink from your repositiory to some outside "safe" area in your file system, protected by file system access rights
- Handle those secrets by means of the keychain / secure enclave, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave)

Anyhow, the biggest / only security risk I see is if you plan to publish your repository and dont't want your secrets to go public. In that case, you would replace those API keys by some text like "[enter your api key here]", which could easily be done by some awk/sed scripting.

Comment: using my actual approach, the app could be published on App Store? I'm concerned about apple rejecting it. Anyway, in your opinion, would it be good practice creating another environment and config file named "forRepo" and publish only that one? putting others in .gitignore (just in case I would need to publish something on GitHub)